# scouting tag - merge proposal

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have [scouting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scouting) which appears to relating to the tactic of scouting, although in this instance specifically to Starcraft 2 related questions. I do not believe we need an additional tag for this and I am of the opinion that it should be merged into [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) as part of the Arqade cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been actioned, meta post wasn't updated.